# Xcode+Swift: UIImageView automatically produces white empty space. How to remove it?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an UIImageView in my VC. I wanted to put an image into it. The imageView has 4 constraints: 8 of distance to all directions. When I load the screen it automatically makes a big white space and I don't know why.

The problem is that I am not sure if its really the UIImageView producing the white space. If I set the content mode to scale to fit there is still an white space. But if I am looking in debugging mode where the space comes from it says from the UIImageView. Here a picture of my debugging so that you hopefully know what I am mean:

[image: White Space Image]

EDIT:
I tried to print out the imageView.frame.height it passes back 0. Can this be? 
In my debugger the imageView.height = 400
Why I can't print out imageView.height? I get an error with "imageView has no member height"

EDIT2:
I tried it now with some different sized pictures ... every time I have a height of 400 in the end

Comment: i think you have problem with constraints. weather you have given 8 to all direction but make sure with parent view. so your parent view appear properly it had to be.

Comment: my parent view is a cell in a table with no defined high. So if I set my down constraint to 500 I have the white spaces +500

Comment: Did you remember to set imageView backgroundColor to clearColor?

Comment: @BjørnRuthberg I dient cleared my background color. How am I doing this?

Comment: imageview.backgroundcolor = uicolor.clear, or do it in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to centre the image set Centre X and Centre Y constraints along with height and width. 
Also try adding this code :

```
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: my content mode is normally scale AspectFit ... I just changed it to scale to fit to show you that the white spaces are not really the image but the white spaces got created by the UIImageView

Comment: can you post the constraints that you are setting?